# Render author with lower case name in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have an author who decided to lower the case of the first letter of both her name and surname as a political act. Problem is `Biber` doesn't agree with it and complains with

```
WARN - Couldn't determine Last Name for name "case, lower" - ignoring name
```

How do I increase `Biber` sensitivity toward political differences?

Please consider the following MWE to replicate the warning message

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{lower_case,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {15},
    number = {5},
    urldate = {2012-10-12},
    journal = {Journal},
    author = {case, lower  and Case, Upper},
    month = jun,
    year = {2012},
    pages = {222--333}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended for biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{lower_case}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this input

```
@article{lower_case,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {15},
    number = {5},
    urldate = {2012-10-12},
    journal = {Journal},
    author = {{case}, {lower}  and Case, Upper},
    month = jun,
    year = {2012},
    pages = {222--333}
}
```

I get

[image]

So also the initial is computed correctly.

Comment: This what I use, essentially (except all my authors are defined as strings) and I've never had problems. I'm not sure it will work properly with e.g. `\Citeauthor{lower_case}` but I'm not entirely sure what the correct thing to do is in that case anyway. [Note that in a sense, 'case' should be 'Case' in the list of references because it occurs at what is essentially the start of a sentence. So would 'Case, l & Case, U.' be more correct? This isn't what I do but I've never been entirely sure whether I handle it correctly.

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure about what *that* user wants; I'd say that if she wants to be lowercase, it should be independently of where the name is.

Comment: That's the policy I follow but there is something odd about starting a sentence with a lowercase letter. If for example, an author wants to avoid highlighting their name through capitalisation, starting a sentence in lowercase seems to draw attention to the very fact they were anxious not to focus on.

Comment: @cfr Good point. I think I would use the lower case in bibliography but I would use a upper case whether the name happen to be the first word of the sentence (By the way, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danah_boyd) seems to follow this style.